# find number of divisors of number, for t test cases

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

Number of test cases are t, where `1<=t<=1000` number n, `1<=n<=1000000000`. This is the code i have tried,but getting time out is there any better approach for this , like dynamic programming.. if any please suggest me the code

```
public class Main{ 
    public static void main(String args[])throws java.lang.Throwable{
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
            System.out.println(factors(Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine())));
        }
    }
    public static int factors(int number){
        int count;
        int result=1;
        for (int i = 2; i<=(number); i++){
            count=0;
            while (number % i == 0) {
                number /= i;
                count++;
            }
            if(count == 0)
                continue;
            result*=(count+1);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) says, that every integer greater than 1 is either prime or a product of prime numbers. That means that to find all divisors of a number, you need to find its prime factorization at least. Once you have the prime factorization, you can get all the other divisors by multiplying some of the primes. Another approach is to just go through all the reasonable* integers and count the divisors.

Either approach is time consuming, because in the first, you need to

1. Find the primes - not easy, but you don't necessarily have to go one by one and test. Prime factorization can be found e.g. by recursion.
2. Find all combinations of these primes that the combination is lower than sqrt(n).

in the second, you just go one by one and test, which is obviously time consuming.

---

*reasonable integers are those that are lower than square root of `n` as it is the highest possible number to divide `n` so trying higher ones is useless.

EDIT: counting to `sqrt(n)` does not give you all the divisors, but just a half of them: when you divide `n` by `q1` which is `<= sqrt(n)`, you get another number `q2` which is `>= sqrt(n)`. By counting only up to `sqrt(n)` you get only the `q1`s, so you must then double the final number and then subtract 1 if `n` is a square number (because you would count `sqrt(n)` two times).